# Get exact match from a string in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza, nzsql

I am trying to extract a substring from a string and do comparison with other string and see if its a complete match or not. Can someone share your thoughts on how to accomplish this using regular expressions. Thank you.

```
**Input column**
abc
abcd

**What I have tried?**
LIKE '%abc%'

**Output** 
abc
abcd
```

But I need only **abc** and discard **abcd** in this case.How can this be done using LIKE. I guess LIKE doesnt support to accomplish which is the reason I am interested to use regex for this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show some examples? Why do you think you need a regex for this?

Comment: Added more details in the question.

Comment: Seems to be either a simple `col = 'abc'` or if you want to treat trailing blanks as non-matching `col LIKE 'abc'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution will depend on how you distinguish 'abc' from 'abcd'.  Based on you question, I infer the answer to that would be the regex idea of word boundaries.

Netezza does not support general regexp functionality in LIKE, so you'll have to use something like the regexp_extract function included the Netezza SQL Extension toolkit.

```
select regexp_extract('abc abcd','\babc\b');

 REGEXP_EXTRACT
----------------
 abc
(1 row)
```

The SQL Extension Toolkit is included with Netezza, but must be configured and made available by your administrator.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure my answer is applicable after your edit.  It seems as if COL1 LIKE 'abc' alone would do the trick for you now.